# Do not restore the perspective

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I have scenario where the perspective opened before closing the rcp application should not restored when the application is restarted.

This is required because, we have the login system implemented and depending on the login-user we need to enable the perspective which the login-user is authorized to.

But when user-A login and opens "perspective A" before closing the application then for user-B "perspective A" is showed by default when user-B login.

I know this is being stored in .metadata folder, but i do not want to clear the metadata folder at runtime (while opening the application)

So while restarting the application, how do i restrict the workbench not to open the last opened perspective?

I have tried overriding the getInitialWindowPerspectiveId() of workbenchadvisor class but no use.

I also tried, deleting the prespective descriptor from the perspective registry but still no use...

any inputs to solve this is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

if you set following flag, workbench will not store/restore its settings.

```
org.eclipse.ui.application.IWorkbenchConfigurer

public void setSaveAndRestore(boolean enabled);
```

set the above flag in

```
org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor{

public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer) {

configurer.setSaveAndRestore(false);

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i tried with this also before posting the problem here...for some reason it still doesn't work!